# How to get last child from elements including their ancestors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this structure:

```
  <div class="dialogs-container">
    <div class="dialog-1">
      <div class="dialog__locker"></div>
      <div class="dialog__pane dialog__pane_pink">
        <button>Close dialog</button>
        <button>Open top dialog</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-2">
      <div class="dialog__locker"></div>
      <div class="dialog__pane dialog__pane_lightblue dialog__pane_small">
        <button>Close dialog</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How to specify styles only for last element with `dialog__locker` class? Seems to me I can not use `:last-child` pseudo class since it works only for one specified container. I need something like `:last-child` including descendants.

I want to specify background-color & opacity only for `dialog-2 > dialog__locker` in that case?

Dialogs count is not constant. So I can not use `dialog-2` in selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```css
.dialogs-container> :last-child .dialog__locker {
  background: red;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialogs-container">
  <div class="dialog-1">
    <div class="dialog__locker"></div>
    <div class="dialog__pane dialog__pane_pink">
      <button>Close dialog</button>
      <button>Open top dialog</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dialog-2">
    <div class="dialog__locker"></div>
    <div class="dialog__pane dialog__pane_lightblue dialog__pane_small">
      <button>Close dialog</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following too:

```
.dialogs-container [class|="dialog"]:last-child {
  background: red;
  height: 5px;
}
```

I am assuming that you will always name your divs `dialog-<some-number>` nested within `dialogs-container`

Comment: no need to consider class, because last-child we will always take the last-child, so it's useless to add an attribute selector